# How to assign custom property to jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, member

I need to assign a custom property to a jQuery object. Here is the object:

```
var object = $("<div id='item'></div>");
```

I need `object` to have a custom data member. How can I add this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Thanks - worked perfectly. Simple answer to a simple question :)

Answer (score 15):

The .data() function allows you to store or retrieve arbitrary data and associate it with matched elements.

In many situations, it easiest to store key-value-pairs using data() against the body tag.

**Data Storage Example**

```
//Store the string "bar" with the body tag, with the key "foo"
$('body').data('foo', 'bar');
```

**Data Retrieval Example**

```
//Retrieve the string "bar"
var str = $('body').data('foo');
```

**Reference**

- [The Manual](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can add a property to the DOM object incapsulated in the jQuery object.

You can access the DOM object as the first element of any jQuery object.

```
var object = $("<div id='item'></div>");
$(object)[0].aproperty = "any value"
```